# NFS mount and file system

Tags: files

We are planning to use NFS mount in place for sites/default/files and will be mounting the NFS on a Linux machine. Once mounted onto server, and linking it with Drupal file system (through *Public File System* path), are there any other configuration that needs to be taken care of? Please advice

Comment: Depending on the performance of the mount, you might want to use https://www.drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache & https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg/

Comment: Thanks Mikeytown2 for the comment, I will check the performance and try your suggestion

Comment: I'm curious if you have any news/feedback on this. Does it work? What's your experience?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens. We have mounted a NFS folder onto drupal but have not tried any performance tuning yet, the site is still on its beta. So far, so good...